# Is a matrix with complex entries invertable?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

This is merely a question of interest and not for something I am doing in school. I have never seen a matrix with complex entries in class before, but mind you it was a limited linear algebra class, I only saw complex eigenvlues and eigenvectors. I know a matrix cannot be invertible if the det is 0. WHat about a complex determinant?

Comment: Note taht $0 \in \mathbb{C}$, so the criterion is valid even for any matrix with complex entires.

Comment: The facts about invertibility and determinants apply in any field of characteristic zero, and therefore they all work in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matrix with complex entries:
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 + 2i & -2 + i \\
2 - i & -2 - 2i
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And this is its inverse:
$$
A^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
 0.08 - 0.24 i &  0.16 + 0.12 i \\
-0.16 - 0.12 i & -0.12 + 0.16 i
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Further we have $\mbox{det } A = 5-10 i$.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix W has a inverse matrix (field $\mathbb{C}
$ or $\mathbb{R}
$) if and only if $det W \not = 0$

According to  Alexei0709 and myself $0 \in \mathbb{C}
$ or $\mathbb{R}
$

Comment: Did you mean to say it is invertible if and only if $\det W \not = 0$?

Comment: What do you talking about, this is what I have written! ;)

Answer (score 1):

More generally, a matrix $A$ in $M_n(R)$, $R$  a commutative ring, is invertible if and only $\det A$ is a unit in $R$. For instance a matrix in $M_n(\mathbf Z)$ is invertible if and only if $\det A=\pm1$.